# Is $\int_{t-0.5}^{t+0.5}{a(\tau)d\tau}$ also bounded for all $t \in R^{+}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let a(t) be a bounded function. Is $\int_{t-0.5}^{t+0.5}{a(\tau)d\tau}$ also bounded for all $t \in R^{+}$?

Comment: do you mean bounded for all $t\in\Bbb R^+$?

Comment: yes, Indeed
it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\left|\int_{t-p}^{t+p}a(\tau)d\tau\right|\leq \int_{t-p}^{t+p}|a(\tau)|d\tau\leq 2p\|a\|_{\infty}$$
so that the new function is bounded ($p=0.5$).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because $$\left|\int_{t-0.5}^{t+0.5} a(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau\right|\leq\int_{t-0.5}^{t+0.5} |a(\tau)|\,\mathrm d\tau\leq\int_{t-0.5}^{t+0.5}M\,\mathrm d\tau=M$$ because $a$ is bounded, i.e. there exists a $M\in\mathbb R$ such that $|a(\tau)|\leq M$ for all $\tau\in\mathbb R$. Since this is true for all $t\in\mathbb R^+$, the integral is bounded by the same constant $M$.